# Is cloning an object, map or array and then using delete for example, considered immutable?

Tags: javascript

If I have an existing object, array or map and I want to delete or add and item, is copying (shallow copy) a map first for example and then using the delete method on the new map, considered the correct way to maintain immutability?

**EDIT**

In functional languages I've learned like Elixir, data structures such as Lists return a new List. JS doesn't work this way. Even array methods like reduce under the hood are still taking an empty array as an initial parameter, and pushing items 
 (mutating the initial array) into it.

```
const map = new Map([
  ['dog', 'Dog'],
  ['cat', 'Cat'],
  ['chicken', 'Chicken'],
])

const map2 = new Map([
  ...map,
])
map2.delete('dog')
```

Comment: yes, but cloning maps is a very costly operation...

Comment: What do you mean by "considered immutability"? You're modifying the clone, not the original.

Comment: @Barmar I guess I am confused about is it OK (good practice) to create a copy for example of an object, array or map and then use methods like delete, push, etc. to mutate the copy? In languages like Elixir, a new tuple is returned and you never have to worry. I guess Immutable.js does the same thing. Its the using `delete` on a copy that's confusing because your actually mutating a copy.

Comment: Don't use `new Map([
  ...map,
])`. Just do `new Map(map)`.

Comment: "Immutability" means that it's not possible to change something. E.g. strings in JavaScript are immutable because there are no functions that can be used to change them.

Comment: Making a copy of something and then modifying the copy doesn't mean the original is immutable. You can still do `map.delete()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating `map2`. However, on reasonable encapsulation logic (such as putting the clone+delete in a function), it's still considered a pure operation, and the original that you pass as an argument would stay unmutated.

The functions

```
function withoutDog(map) {
    const map2 = new Map(map);
    map2.delete('dog');
    return map2;
}
```

```
function withoutDog(map) {
    return new Map(Array.from(map).filter(([key, _]) => key !== 'dog'));
}
```

are indistinguishable from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

When something is immutable it simply means it does not change state.

Since you are not changing the object's state (i.e. object.foo = 'bar'), rather you are cloning it and mutating the clone, it is immutable.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not an example of immutability.

An object is immutable if it's not possible to modify its contents. Making a copy of an object allows you to modify the copy without modifying the original, but you can still modify the original if you want.

```
const map = new Map([
  ['dog', 'Dog'],
  ['cat', 'Cat'],
  ['chicken', 'Chicken'],
])

const map2 = new Map(map) // clone the Map
map2.delete('dog') // modify the clone -- doesn't affect the original
map.delete('cat') // modify the original -- it's not immutable
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the OP asking if the data structure is immutable, or whether the patterns being used here are immutable? The question is inherently confusing because we typically use immutable as an adjective for data structures, not algorithm implementations; we typically describe algorithm implementations designed for use with immutable data structures as "pure functions" or "pure operations".

According to the usual definition of "immutable", @Barmar is correct that the answer is that the data structures in the question are not immutable, since objects in JS are mutable. Even when we use const declarations, the const keyword just makes the reference to the object immutable, but the values within the object can still be mutated; we're now holding an immutable, atomic reference to a mutable, compound value.

But the OP's wording ("is cloning ... considered immutable") suggests that really the question is asking whether the process in question is immutable. Therefore, @Bergi's answer is a good attempt to answer the question as it seems intended, by parsing "immutable" as "pure". If this logic were encapsulated in an API, that API would provide a pure operation / function to callers, even though the implementation would not be internally pure, since it modifies a local value before returning it.